# Proving the father of Elijah Butterfield born 1792 in Washington County, New York

Tags: new-york-state, american-revolution

Need help getting my [DAR](https://www.dar.org/) application approved.  The only ancestor I haven't proved yet is the link between Elijah Butterfield born November 24, 1792 in Kingsbury, Washington County, New York, and his father Nathaniel Butterfield born April 14, 1761 in Chelmsford, Massachusetts.  Elijah's mother was Esther Stewart.

Elijah died in 1827 but when Esther (his mother) applied for a pension in 1842 she named her surviving children as Elijah's brothers. The eldest brother became Elijah's children's guardian.

How can I locate documentary proof that Elijah's father was Nathaniel Butterfield?

Comment: What evidence do you have that leads you to believe Elijah's father was Nathaniel, and how do you know who Elijah's mother was?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Which part of the process do you need help with? Neither your post nor its title contain an answerable question, which makes it unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything at americanancestors.org.

Comment: Elijah died in 1827 but when Esther (his mother) applied for a pension in 1842 she named her surviving children as Elijah''s brothers. The eldest brother became Elijah's childrens guardian.

Comment: Hi Jan. What I'm asking for is if anyone may have documented proof that Elijah's father was Nathaniel Butterfield. Nathaniel was born in 1761 and died in 1793.

Comment: Thank you for checking that source Ellen, that's one I've never heard of.

Comment: @Linda It's the site of the New England Genealogical and Historical Society. You need to be a member to access it.

Comment: An article, *The Butterfields of Middlesex*,  in  [NEHGR, vol 44](https://archive.org/stream/newenglandhistorv44wate#page/n63),seems to cut off before your ancestor, but may be of some use. (The immigrant ancestor Benjamin and his son Samuel are in my linage)

Comment: Thank you user2448131, I will look into that article. I may have seen it before but I have looked at so many its hard to recall.

Comment: Just a reminder -- the [tour] gives a quick overview of the site and the [help] has more information about how the site works.  We shouldn't answer questions in comments. You can add information to your question by using the edit link underneath it.